# Error while installation of poppler on Windows 7 via conda

Tags: python-3.x, poppler

I am trying to install poppler on my virtual environment (Python 3.6) as I am trying to install pdf2text and I want to use pytesseract. I am installing poppler as a dependency.

I am installing through the terminal and I am always getting the following error:

ERROR conda.core.link:_exwecute(568): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-hc6833c9_1'.
OSError(22, 'Invalid Argument')

Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 22] Invalid Argument: 'C:\Users\abarat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\abhi\Library\resources\icudt1.dat'

I have tried running on Python 2.7 environment and 3.6 as well. I tried installing with the binary from the website and add it to the environment variable but I do not have access due to IT restrictions.

Expected: poppler installed
Actual: Not installed